# Container with post, using MySQL, and PHP - Change Article on click right arrow

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I created a database with an articles table that will contain 18 articles for now... in my web page I created a container where only 9 articles should be visible and then pressing an arrow will load the other 9 obviously hiding the previous 9 articles... my questions are: how can I make PHP export me from the database only the first 9 and not all at once with the usual while loop (passing from MySQL fetch assoc)? Second: how do I once I have seen the first 9 articles, clicking on the arrow, go on with the other 9 articles in the database? Do I put them all in an array and then use a slice and an auto-incrementing counter?

Answer (score 1):

Your efforts are required, To achieve you need basic knowledge of PHP, MYSQL queries, Ajax, Jquery Ajax, on click event in ajax (or you can use plain javascript over jQuery)

**first:** how can I make php export me from the database only the first 9 and not all at once with the usual while loop (passing from mysql fetch assoc)?

**You have to use LIMIT in your query, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp**

**Second:** how do I once I have seen the first 9 articles, clicking on the arrow, go on with the other 9 articles in the database?

**You can either use Ajax call or pass next set in query string
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp**

**Do I put them all in an array and then use a slice**
Yes, you need to put them in array in such a fashion that is easy to loop. Slicing is not required.

**and an auto-incrementing counter?**

You have to first understand no. of ajax requests are required to all records.
Lets say, you have 40 records and you want to show 9 records per arrow click then maximum 5 arrow clicks are required to show 40 records. click 1 - 9 recs , click 2 - 9 recs,....so on .... and click 5 - 4 recs

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 9
```

But you must calculate all field as pagination system.

This will help you [pagination](https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html)